# TimeOfDay without seconds and millisecond

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc web application, where StartDate is of type `DateTime?`:-

```
@item.StartDate.Value.TimeOfDay
```

The above will display the current time including seconds and milliseconds such as, which i do not want :-

```
10:17:54.6023744
```

but is there a way to display only the hour:minutes with either AM or PM ??
Thanks

Comment: Use formatting and an appropriate format string. For instance HH:mm will display 24 hour with minutes only date

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`DateTime` has an overload of `ToString()` which allows you to pass a [custom format](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19677/Formats-for-DateTime-ToString).

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
String strDate="";
strDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");   // 07/21/2007 
strDate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");   //Saturday, 21 July 2007
strDate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"); // Saturday, 21 July 2007 14:58
strDate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt"); // Saturday, 21 July 2007 03:00 PM
strDate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy H:mm"); // Saturday, 21 July 2007 5:01 
strDate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy h:mm tt"); // Saturday, 21 July 2007 3:03 PM
strDate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"); // Saturday, 21 July 2007 15:04:10
strDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"); // 07/21/2007 15:05
strDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"); // 07/21/2007 03:06 PM
strDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm"); // 07/21/2007 15:07
strDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt"); // 07/21/2007 3:07 PM
strDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); // 07/21/2007 15:09:29
strDate = dt.ToString("MMMM dd"); // July 21
strDate = dt.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK"); // 2007-07-21T15:11:19.1250000+05:30    
strDate = dt.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'"); // Sat, 21 Jul 2007 15:12:16 GMT
strDate = dt.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"); // 2007-07-21T15:12:57
strDate = dt.ToString("HH:mm"); // 15:14
strDate = dt.ToString("hh:mm tt"); // 03:14 PM
strDate = dt.ToString("H:mm"); // 5:15
strDate = dt.ToString("h:mm tt"); // 3:16 PM
strDate = dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); // 15:16:29
strDate = dt.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"); // 2007-07-21 15:17:20Z
strDate = dt.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"); // Saturday, 21 July 2007 15:17:58
strDate = dt.ToString("yyyy MMMM"); // 2007 July
```

Comment: can we add a default time from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104633/how-to-add-date-picker-bootstrap-3-on-mvc-5-project-using-the-razor-engine) bootstrap date picker eg: `datepicker value + TimeofDay` ?

Answer (score 5):

This will do it for you:

```
@item.StartDate.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the ToString(string) overload and specify the format:

```
StartDate.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

This would be the same as

```
StartDate.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

Comment: OP wants to have time in `hours`,`minutes` with `AM` or `PM` but not with `seconds` so instead of  `ss` `tt`  would help him IMO

Comment: Right, I've changed it

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this:

```
StartDate.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET 4 or later, you can specify a format string when converting to a string:

```
@item.StartDate.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString("hh mm tt")
```

But why not just format the date/time appropriately without extracting TimeOfDay?  This will work in earlier versions of .NET too:

```
@item.StartDate.Value.ToString("hh mm tt")
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

So Ideally it would be

```
@item.StartDate.Value.Date
```

EDIT:

I didn't read the question correctly, take a look here [DateTime.ToString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Please read the question once again.

Comment: Ahhh... Yup, I see now. Good call. Maybe this would be helpful [DateTime Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: it would be nice if you can edit your answer with above comment/link.