# How to add Date Picker Bootstrap 3 on MVC 5 project using the Razor engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I need some guide lines on how to install a [Date Picker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) Bootstrap 3 on a MVC 5 project using the Razor engine. I found this link [here](http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.in/2013/01/twitterbootstrapmvc4-meet-bootstrap.html) but couldn't make it work in VS2013.

Copying from the example in the later link above I've already done the following:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",    // ** NEW for Bootstrap Datepicker
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css",  // ** NEW for Bootstrap Datepicker
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Then I've added the script to the index view as follow

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datepicker').datepicker(); //Initialise any date pickers
</script>
}
```

Now, how to call the date picker here?

```
   <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DropOffDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DropOffDate, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here..." })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DropOffDate)
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us your cshtml/Razor code you are working with that does not work. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated my post accordingly

Comment: I'll fire up VS and see if I can figure it out!

Comment: Did you use NuGet to add the files or did you add them manually ?

Comment: waqar ahmed is by far the simplest solution.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This answer uses the [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), which is a separate include.  There are other ways to do this without including jQuery UI.

First, you simply need to add the `datepicker` class to the textbox, in addition to `form-control`:

```
<div class="form-group input-group-sm">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DropOffDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DropOffDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here..." })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DropOffDate)
</div>
```

Then, to be sure the javascript is triggered after the textbox is rendered, you have to put the datepicker call in the jQuery ready function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { // will trigger when the document is ready
       $('.datepicker').datepicker(); //Initialise any date pickers
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah this is exactly how I have my code right now and it's not working

Comment: This is why I use Foundation! I have the same thing you do, I tried '@class = "form-control datepicker"' & '@class = "datepicker form-control"' and no dice

Comment: If, by any chance, you are calling it in a partial view, the script must be in the Index page or it won't work if it is the partial view. This was also one of the problems fixed

Comment: Can I automate Razor so that if there `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` is defined on a field it should automatically add the `datepicker` css class and run the js?

Comment: When using JS/JQ within Partial Views, I've found using
[Forloop HtmlHelpers](https://bitbucket.org/forloop/forloop-htmlhelpers/wiki/Home) really helpful. It makes it a lot easier to compartmentalise scripts within EditorTemplates and DisplayTemplates, aswell as in standard Partial Views. It's not perfect in every scenario, but I've found it helped solve a lot of issues similar to this one.

Comment: The MVC 5 templates I have in Visual Studio 2015 don't include JQuery UI so I'm pretty sure you have to install and reference that first before this will work.  There's a decent discussion here with links to related tutorials: https://forums.asp.net/t/1975676.aspx?Tutorial+for+Adding+Datepicker+in+MVC+5

Comment: Same a @EricB here. This just dosn't work from the go. Why did razor not have any datepicker in it's Html object ? Why modern browser like firefox and edge dosn't support a simple <input type="date"> ....

Comment: Chrome supports <input type="date"> but it's garbage.  Picking a date is a complicated UI so its better done by a library.

Comment: new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here..." } }

Answer (score 62):

This answer simply applies the [**`type=date` attribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) to the HTML `input` element and relies on the browser to supply a date picker.  Note that even in 2017, not all browsers provide their own date picker, so you may want to provide a fall back.

All you have to do is add attributes to the property in the view model. Example for variable `Ldate`:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
Public DateTime Ldate {get;set;}
```

Assuming you're using MVC 5 and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: This is THE BEST answer! Is there any way to pick the time and date?  `[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }` didn't work for me.

Comment: The simplest solution is here

Comment: That is NOT the correct answer! That solution will only enable browser specific calendars appear on the browser for date fields. That has nothing to do with Bootstrap Datetime plugin.

Comment: Is there a way i could use this for month selection. A normal text box in bootstrap type="month". How to do this with data annotations?

Comment: Great answer. Yeah it has nothing to do with bootstrap, because why bother with bootstrap when you can append this to your data type.

Comment: This will not working with IE 11 and FF 38. Only Chrome will pick this up.

Comment: The other issue with this solution is that when editing the date field, I just see "mm/dd/yyyy" instead of the date value that already exists.

Comment: Pfff, chrome only solution, until every browser has it's own datepicker

Comment: What goes in the View? `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateFrom)` just shows the date as a string. Using Chrome btw

Comment: Got it - `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateFrom)`

Answer (score 20):

**Add just these two lines before the datetime property in your model**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)] 
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

and result will be :[image: Date Picker in MVC Application]

Comment: But will you use in the View? I tried TextBoxFor but it's still a textbox

Comment: This method only works in some browsers like, chrome.

Comment: IE will fail your solution !

Comment: If anyone had this error: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined. This fixed it

Answer (score 19):

I hope this can help someone who was faced with my same problem.

This answer uses the **Bootstrap DatePicker Plugin**, which is not native to bootstrap.

Make sure you install Bootstrap DatePicker through NuGet

Create a small piece of JavaScript and name it DatePickerReady.js save it in Scripts dir. This will make sure it works even in non HTML5 browsers although those are few nowadays.

```
if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
    $(function () {

       $(".datecontrol").datepicker();

    });
}
```

Set the bundles

```
bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
              "~/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js",
              "~/Scripts/respond.js"))

bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"))
```

Now set the Datatype so that when EditorFor is used MVC will identify what is to be used.

```
<Required>
<DataType(DataType.Date)>
Public Property DOB As DateTime? = Nothing
```

Your view code should be

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.DOB, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control datecontrol", .PlaceHolder = "Enter Date of Birth"}})
```

and voila

[image]

Comment: P.S. - Set the bundles in BundleConfig.cs file in App_Start folder.

Comment: Where do you update the part that reads <Required>
<DataType(DataType.Date)>
Public Property DOB As DateTime? = Nothing

Comment: This appears to be VB.NET, for those tearing their hair out. Tried to convert it to c# but no matter what I tried it did nothing.

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but too many details to replicate your solution.  For example, I don't have a Scripts folder, nor a Bundles folder, which your code apparently expects to be filled with certain scripts?

Answer (score 8):

Attempting to provide a concise update, based on **[Enzero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696406/enzero)**'s answer.

- Install the **Bootstrap.Datepicker** package.

  ```
  PM> install-package Bootstrap.Datepicker
  ...
  Successfully installed 'Bootstrap.Datepicker 1.7.1' to ...
  ```
- In *AppStart/BundleConfig.cs*, add the related scripts and styles in the bundles.

  ```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
        //...,
        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
        "~/Scripts/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.YOUR-LOCALE-CODE-HERE.min.js"));

  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
        ...,
        "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"));
  ```
- In the related view, in the scripts' section, enable and customize datepicker.

  ```
  @section scripts{
      <script type="text/javascript">
          //...
          $('.datepicker').datepicker({
              format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', //choose the date format you prefer
              language: "YOUR-LOCALE-CODE-HERE",
              orientation: 'left bottom'
          });
      </script>
  ```
- Eventually add the *datepicker* class in the related control. For instance, in a TextBox and for a date format in the like of "31/12/2018" this would be:

  ```
  @Html.TextBox("YOUR-STRING-FOR-THE-DATE", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker" })
  ```

Comment: Hi, how do you make this a date range, i.e. user needs to pick two dates from & to

Comment: I'd love to apply this but I don't have BundleConfig.cs.  Razor Pages .net core 2 MVVM architecture.

Answer (score 4):

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

decorate your model like this.
can use a bootstrap date time picker I used this one.
https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I suppose you already have bundles for bootstrap css and js

Your date picker bundle entries

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datePicker").Include(
           "~/Scripts/moment.min.js",
           "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/datepicker").Include(
                 "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"));
```

Render bundles on your Layout View

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/datepicker")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datePicker")
```

Your HTML in view

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "lead col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { @class = "datetimepicker form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
```

At the end of your view add this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'lll'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please consider that the input type "date" (set by Datatype.Date) is only supported by Chrome, Safari and Opera right now (as you can see here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp).

Comment: @leiseliesel I've updated the answer with usage of a bootstrap date time picker.

Answer (score 3):

1.make sure you ref jquery.js at first
2.check layout,make sure you call "~/bundles/bootstrap"
3.check layout,see render section Scripts position,it must be after "~/bundles/bootstrap"
4.add class "datepicker" to textbox
5.put $('.datepicker').datepicker(); in $(function(){...});

Answer (score 1):

Add `@type = "date"` on your code :

```
{ @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here...", @type = "date" }
```

Comment: This one is money

Answer (score -1):

Checkout Shield UI's [Date Picker for MVC](http://demos.shieldui.com/mvc/datepicker/basic-usage). A powerful component that you can integrate with a few lines like:

```
@(Html.ShieldDatePicker()
    .Name("datepicker"))
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
Public DateTime Ldate {get;set;}
```