# How to install bootstrap-datepicker as a component in MVC 5?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, datepicker

Using this [link](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=component&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=linked&language=en&orientation=auto&autoclose=on&todayHighlight=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) and this one [here](http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.in/2013/01/twitterbootstrapmvc4-meet-bootstrap.html) plus the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104633/how-to-add-date-picker-bootstrap-3-on-mvc-5-project-using-the-razor-engine) I was able to install the component as a "Text input" type. Now, I want to change it to a "Component" type
but I don't know how to implement it correctly in MVC5 using the Razor engine.

```
<div class="input-append date">
```

```
$('#sandbox-container .input-append.date').datepicker({
todayBtn: "linked",
autoclose: true,
todayHighlight: true
```

});

This is what I have tried, but doesn't work: The glyph is displayed correctly. The calendar pops if the text box is clicked, but clicking the glyph doesn't do anything. If I remove the
"#sandbox-container" from the script below, then the calendar pops when the glyph is clicked, however it is independent from the one in the text and selecting a date doesn't move it into the text input control.

> ```
>     <div class="input-group">
>         @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PickUpDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker "})
>         <span class="input-group-addon input-append date  glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
>     </div>
> ```

```
    $(function () {                      // will trigger when the document is ready
        $('#sandbox-container .input-append.date').datepicker({
            todayBtn: "linked",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not an acceptable description of your problem. Are you getting an error message? If so, add that to your answer. Otherwise, describe what's happening/not happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem with bootstrap-datetimepicker (based on bootstrap-datepicker). The component code doesn't seem to have been updated for compatibility with Bootstrap 3. It's kind of stupidly looking for a particular format for the addons (Bootstrap 2 style) instead of relying on specific classes on the "buttons". I fixed it by simply implementing my own component setup (basically bypassing the built in version).

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group">
    @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue.ToString(), new { type = "date", @class = "form-control" })
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default datetimepicker-reset">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default datetimepicker-show">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

That's a direct paste from my project, so let me explain a little. First, I have this in an EditorTemplate (which wouldn't be a bad idea for you to implement as well). The `Html.TextBox` bit is customized for that purpose. Passing the empty string for the name parameter lets Razor fill this with the right field name, and the `ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue` is how you get at the current value without specifying a model for the view. Also, I'm using font-awesome instead of the default glyphicons included in Bootstrap, so you can simply adjust the font classes accordingly. That code goes into `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Date.cshtml`. Then, you just need to specify the data type on your property, if you haven't already:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime MyDateProperty { get; set; }
```

Finally, all you need in your view to render all the HTML is:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDateProperty)
```

Then, you just need a little bit of extra JavaScript to wire everything up. I would suggest keeping this generic so you don't need to write the same code over and over for each instance of a date field. I just select all inputs of type "date":

```
$('input[type=date]').datetimepicker()
    .each(function () {
        var $input = $(this);
        var $parent = $input.parent();
        $parent.find('.datetimepicker-reset').on('click', function () {
            $input.val('');
            $input.datetimepicker('update');
        });
        $parent.find('.datetimepicker-show').on('click', function () {
            $input.datetimepicker('show');
        });
    });
```

Here, I'm just using the manual show method of bootstrap-datetimepicker. For the reset/clear button, you just set the value to empty and then tell bootstrap-datetimepicker to update so it recognizes this new value instead of still showing the old value selected in its control.

Comment: That javascript saved me one hell of a headache! Thanks! You rock!