# datepicker is not a function- attempting to load a datepicker on an MVC form field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-datepicker

I am getting the error "**$(...).datepicker() is not a function** as I try to set a bootstrap datepicker on a form field in my MVC/razor form. I've read similar posts and can't seem to get their solutions to work. It seems like the order of dependencies matters. Any advice would be appreciated. I've referenced this as one solution I've tried without success. [How to add Date Picker Bootstrap 3 on MVC 5 project using the Razor engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104633/how-to-add-date-picker-bootstrap-3-on-mvc-5-project-using-the-razor-engine)

**Script Block**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();

    });
</script>
```

**Form Field**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TrainingDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrainingDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TrainingDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Not related, but you do not need both the minified and non-minified versions of jquery

Comment: @StephenMuecke: That's the first thing I noticed too.
There is never a need for both, and I think it could cause problems, though I don't know that it's the cause of this particular one.

Comment: Do you have any other copies of jquery in the view added after your datepicker.js file?

Comment: I do not have any other copies of jquery. Just what I've included in my code

Comment: for alternative you can try jquery-ui datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some conflict on your jquery. Also you have to remove jquery library so remove this one `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>` .

for no conflict on jquery, you can do your code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();

    });
</script>
```